# Selenium: what's the right object type and name I should use in find_element?

Tags: selenium

Given the following object:

```
<div class="myinput_login">
    <label class="item item-input myinput_login_1">
      <i class="icon ion-android-contact placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input class="sn ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" type="text" placeholder="Please enter the inverter SN" ng-model="remoteLoginData.uuid" style="">
    </label>
</div>
```

I am trying to automate the input of my Serial Number into the object. I've already tried to find the element by name, id, class_name, but I always get a "no such element" error.

So the questions are:

- What element type should I be searching by?
- What is the value of the object name I should be searching for? "sn", "sn ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched", or?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the above snippet from a website? can you give its link?

Comment: It is part of the Solax PV portal application they provide to their customers. It is behind user credentials so unless you're a customer, you wouldn't be able to access it. Since yesterday I also realised that part, so I will also have to include that portion into my script. Just an FYI, the goal is to automate triggering my inverter to charge the batteries, when the grid energy cost is below a certain value. Solax aren't playing ball to provide an API for that :-( So I'm going the web automation way instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these two

```
box= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Please enter the inverter SN"]')))

box=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.sn.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-empty.ng-touched')))

box.click()
box.send_keys('Serial Number')
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will give that a go and let you know.

Comment: Yes, the first one appeared to have worked great! Thank you. :-)
The second one not so much.
Also, how would I trigger a press the "Login" button below it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for an xpath to use?

```
//div[contains(@class,'myinput_login')]//input
```

Comment: No. I'm a noob at this, so trying to figure out my way using Selenium to then script the selection of my inverter using Python, so that I can enable an on/off option after that. I don't really understand much of it yet, but thank you for your suggestion anyway.